# NSURLSession ignoring NSURLSessionConfiguration Cache Policy

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration

Even after setting the Cache Policy, my `NSURLSession` is still loading cached data:

```
let url = NSURL(string: urlString);
var sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration();
sessionConfig.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;
var session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig);
```

Is there a reason why the session is ignoring the `.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData`?

Comment: How are you checking that the session is "ignoring" the cache policy?

Comment: @Mundi: I am printing out the data that is returned by the session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error). I then change the file on the server, and the printout in the console is still the same.

Answer (score 2):

From [NSURLRequest Class Reference page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/enum/c:@E@NSURLRequestCachePolicy)

```
NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData = 4, // Unimplemented
NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData = 5 // Unimplemented
```

I guess, the constant is there but should not be used.